# Visual Studio can't start Azure Debugging Environment

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure

Debugging my Azure app has been working fine for months.  However, for no reason that I can find, I just started getting this when I F5....

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Access is denied
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How do I resolve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Clean the project and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solved] Reinstalled Windows Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio and rebooted.